# Create account on Parse with Unity3D

Tags: c#, parse-platform, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a new account using the parse api with Unity and running into all kinds of trouble. All I would like to do is create a account on parse. Then on success load a scene.

This is the code used to create a new account.

```
bool success = true;
string error;
try
{
    Task signup = user.SignUpAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        if (t.IsFaulted || t.IsCanceled)
        {
            success = false;
        }
    });
}
catch (System.Exception e)
{
    error = "Failed to sign up Parse User. Reason: " + e.Message;
    success = false;
}

if(success)
    Application.LoadLevel("ExampleScene");
```

I wont post all the things I have tried because I have tried a lot of things.

The main problems that always occur:

- The code is ASync so it does not wait for the account to be created
  at all.
- If I use a IEnumerator to wait it fails as it cannot yield inside a
  try catch.
- Even if I take the try catch out Unity complains that LoadLevel
  cannot be called from the main thread.
- I tried passing a callback. To the ContinueWith call but that still
  complains about calling Load from the main thread.

So what it boils down to is that I cannot figure out how to wait for the task to finish without disabling all Unity functionality.

How am I supposed to go about creating a parse account and getting notified when it is finished and then call Unity functions again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can yield your Task like this for this case:

```
private IEnumerator SignUpHandler()
{
    bool success = true;
    string error;

    Task signup = user.SignUpAsync();//.ContinueWith(t =>
    while (!signup.IsCompleted) yield return null;
    if (signup.IsFaulted || signup.IsCanceled)
    {
        //Debug.Log("Error " + signup.Exception.Message);
        error = "Failed to sign up Parse User. Reason: " + signup.Exception.Message;
        success = false;
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Done");
        Application.LoadLevel("ExampleScene");
    }

}
```

and call your SignUpHandler from somewhere like this: `StartCoroutine("SignUpHandler");`

Comment: That works great, I need to be able to try catch the yield line though. Is there anyway to do that? I can try catch the startcoroutine call but that doesnt seem to catch the exception.

Comment: Actually you don't need a try catch block for this, checking if IsFaulted or IsCancelled provides the same operation for this. [Also you can take a look at this post for handling errors.](https://www.parse.com/questions/unity-sdk-handling-errors)

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. I wasted so much time on this. Wish I could +1 more.